# can case statement be used in calling procedure at runtime

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Is this possible :-

```
EXEC PROC1 (case when 1=2 then A else B).
```

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens? (Should take less time than writing a SO question.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line (case when 1=2 then 'A' else 'B' end);
B

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Sorry, but where is the procedure name in this?

Comment: `dbms_output.put_line` is a procedure.